# Issue with to change background when hovering on li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have image back ground with the following css code, which works perfect.

```
body {     
    background: url('/images/back.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have the following link on the page

```
<ul class='doIt'>
<li class='nav'></li>
<li class='nav'></li>
<li class='nav'></li>
</ul>
```

What I need is when I hover on the

Element I want the following css take place on the full page.

```
#back {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 89;
}
```

In short when the hover on the li element cover up the body image with this opacity Id.

I have tried as follows, but not working at all.

```
$('.nav').hover(function(){
    $('#back').show();  
    $('#back').animate({opacity: '0.5' }, 1000);  

  }, function() {
        $('#back').stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500); 
        $('#back').hide(1);       
  });
```

Some one help Please!

Comment: Look at CSS transitions; they might make your world a lot easier with this stuff: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: What is `#back`? Can you create an example?

Comment: I doubt it. OP is `show()`ing `#back` so it wouldn't be `body`.

Comment: #back is a div element which suppose to cover up the page when called by JS.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have no elements with `back` applied as id, so your script fails while is trying to look for that element. In case you've not included it in the question, please provide a minimal example to see (codepen or jsfiddle) but, assuming that the element exists I can only suppose that, as soon as you hover a `list-item`, that div overlaps all the elements because of its greater `z-index` value, so you lose the hover state.

Anyway there's no need to use javascript for this task: you may define a huge semi-transparent outline to the `list-item` when it is hovered, e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgZzPz

```
li:hover {
  outline: 999em rgba(0,0,0, .8) solid;
}
```

or you may apply this style on `ul:hover` if it looks better for you. You could also show it with a simple css transition (e.g. with a `0.5` seconds duration, as in your example):

```
li {
  outline: 999em rgba(0,0,0, 0) solid;
  transition: outline .5s;
}

li:hover {
  outline-color:rgba(0,0,0, .8);
}
```

Comment: the problem seems I have many element on the page and it would be difficult to handle in z-index.

Comment: i wish if i could get Jquery code to work on because of my Layout complexity, is that possible?

Comment: you need to share a link with the minimal code, including your `#back` element. Anyway that element has a great `z-index`, so I suppose that as soon as you hover the list-item, that div overlaps all the elements so you lose the hover state